# Stm32 Blue Pill Internal ADC Voltage Reference Configuration

Tags: arduino-ide, adc, stm32

I am programming an STM32F103C8T6 Board in Arduino IDE. I want to change the value of the internal Voltage Reference for the ADC. How can I achieve this in Arduino ide?

Comment: What do you mean you want to change the value? The value is 1.2V. That's not something you can change. Do you mean you want to *use* the internal reference voltage? Or that you want to use some other external voltage as the reference voltage?

Comment: unlike AVRs, stm32 internal voltage reference can't be used as a measurement max reference. it's there just for application calibration. your reference only depends on the VDDA pin and  1) it has to be always connected to a supply and 2) must be between 2~3.6V

Comment: I want to change change the internal reference voltage, to something else other than the 1.2 v fixed reference. Like in avr microcontrollers, there is an external adc voltage reference pin for setting the reference voltage. Thats all.

Comment: Which Arduino? The IDE is an interface to lots of chips, and they will have different ways of setting the ADC reference voltage.